# How to remove an specific node from a graph in recursive function in R

Tags: r, function, recursion, vertices, del

I am new in R. I have a recursive function in R and want to remove specific node with its connected edges from a graph.
This is my code inside recursive function:

```
recursive.gr <- function(gg,current_node,target_node) 
  {
    switch(as.character(current_node_neighbors_count), 
         '0'={
              gg <- add.edges(gg,c(current_node,target_node),attr=list(width=5))
              return(gg)
             },
         '1'={
           print("1 neighbore")
           xi<-neighbors(gg,current_node)
           #gg<-delete.edges(gg,which(as_edgelist(gg)==current_node,arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])
           gg<-delete.vertices(gg,which(as_adj_list(gg,"all")==current_node,arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])
              return(recursive.gr(gg,current_node,target_node))
             },
             {#switch default
                     return(gg)
             }

          )
}
```

Call f<-recursive.gr(g,source_node,target_node)

I used delete.vertices and delete.edges instead but i got this error

> Error in as.igraph.vs(graph, source) :    Cannot use a vertex sequence
>   from another graph.

Thanks for your guides.

Comment: What is `current_node_neighbors_count`  ?